# Checkbox по типу "выбрать всё" срабатывает только единожды (1 раз выбирает, 1 раз убирает всё)

Tags: jquery

Имеется вот такой код

```
$('input[name=select_all]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('value')=="false"){
        $('input[name="themes[]"]').attr('checked',true);
        $(this).attr('value','true');
    }
    else{
        $('input[name="themes[]"]').attr('checked',false);
        $(this).attr('value','false');
    }
});
```

но он работает лишь ЕДИНОЖДЫ. т.е. 1 раз все чекбоксы нужные выбираются, потом ещё раз с них всех снимется выборка. Потом НЕ РАБОТАЕТ. Никак не могу понять, почему. При этом после 1 раза всё верно "заходит" в конструкции if/else (обе части), проверял отладочным выводом типа "alert(1)/(2)". Ткните, пожалуйста, где собака зарыта :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главная проблема, что надо делать prop вместо attr,

я бы написал это так

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $inputs=$('input[name="themes[]"]');
    $('input[name=select_all]').change(function () {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        console.log(checked);
        $inputs.prop('checked', checked);
    });
});
```

hhtp://jsfiddle.net/oceog/tW7Jq/